# How to iterate through a folder in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iteration, discord.js

I am trying to iterate through a folder of command files to make a help command for a discord bot.
This is my code so far.

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'help',
  description: 'Lists current commands.',
  execute(message) {
    //was the first time i made something interesting out of a for loop
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '$help') {
      const commands = 'C:/Bot/commands';
      const Discord = require('discord.js');
      const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Commands")
        .setColor(0x6e7175)
        .setFooter('Provided by Echo', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/748282903997186178/6288e1f487e111b211aa9966c583d948.png?size=128')
        .setTimestamp()

      for (i of commands) {
        let title = i.name
        let value = i.description
        helpEmbed.addField(title, value)
      }
      message.channel.send(helpEmbed)
    }
  }
}
```

C:/Bot/commands is the folder in which all the commands are stored, at the moment i.name and i.description are undefined. What's the issue here?

Comment: how does commands structure look like?

Answer (score 1):

`C:/Bot/commands` is the folder with stored comands, but string 'C:/Bot/commands' is not a folder - it is a string.

For iterate through folder you need to read it by [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) or sync version

Answer (score 1):

`commands` is currently just a string. If you want to get an array of all files in a folder, use `fs`.

```js
const fs = require('fs'); // node.js built in module
const files = fs.readdierSync('../commands'); // get the names of all files in the foler

for (file of files) {
 // now you can require the file
 const { name, description } = require(`../commands/${file}`);
 embed.addField(name, description);
}
```